# Start and stop with the same div (javascript-jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to start and stop an animation when click on the same div.

```
$('div').click(function(){  

//if is the first click -->do animation in loop
//if is the second click--->stop animation

});
```

How do u do it?

I had resolve only the animation start with loop:

```
var play = 0;

function myAnimateGreen(){

        $('green').animate(
            {left:'+250px'},
            1000, 
            );          
        while(play==1) {myAnimateGreen();}  
    }

$('green').click(function(){
    play = 1;   
    myAnimateGreen();}
});
```

But I can't resolve the stop!

Comment: Check whether `play` is already 1, then set it to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector to detect if the animation is currently happening

```
$('div').click(function(){  
   if( !$(".green").is(':animated') ) {
      //Do animation
   } else {
      //Stop animation
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function animateGreen(el) {
    var delay = 500,
        time = 1000,
        distance = 150;
    el.animate({left:'+='+distance+'px'}, time, "linear");
    el.data("anim_green", setTimeout(animateGreen, time+delay, el));
}

$('green').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.data("anim_green")) {
        clearTimeout(self.data("anim_green"));
        self.data("anim_green", false);
        return;
    }
    animateGreen(self);
});
```

Should do it, just paste! Proof: http://jsbin.com/ajagij/3/edit

Comment: It works! But if I click againg after stop, it doesn't restart. How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Now, you can add delays (So you can click it!!), time and distance easier too ;)

Comment: Excellent example (except for using jsBin instead of jsFiddle). +1